# What is the name of this inequality: If $a>0, b>0, c>0$ and $a<b+c$ then $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$?

Tags: inequality

What is the name of this inequality?

> If $a>0, b>0, c>0$ and $a<b+c$ then $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$

Comment: Don't think there's any particular name. Just squaring proves it by positivity of $2\sqrt{bc}$.